# Execute a program using a C program

Tags: c

is it possible to write a C program that reads another program line by line and make it(2nd program) execute? please help

Comment: What do you mean "reads another program line by line"? Reads the source code?

Comment: It sounds like you want to write an interpreter in C. This is possible.

Comment: This question is too vague to be satisfactorily answered, as shown by the variety of answers.  What do you mean "reads another program line by line and make it execute?"  Do you want a compiler?  An interpreter?  The equivalent of a shell script that uses the existing compiler to compile a program and then run the output?  All of these are possible, and all are different things.  (Also, what language will the second program be in?)

Answer (score 1):

Yes.

But the details are complicated and depend on many things that you don't specify in your question.

- What language is the second program written in?
- Why you want to do this will affect how it should be done
- Are you looking to control the 2nd program in some advanced way?
- etc.

Comment: i m doing the 2nd program also in C(as for now). i am trying to make a program  equivalent to the operation of shell

Comment: @ask: How will the 2ndProgram be read by the 1stProgram? Will 2ndProgram be read in as source code, or as a compiled binary? You may want to edit and clarify your question.

Comment: @ask: consider C shell :))) The language is not exactly C though.

Answer (score 1):

It's called an interpreter. Google for "C interpreter".

Answer (score 1):

yes, with [exec](http://it.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exec_%28Unix%29) on unix and [ShellExecute](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb762153%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) on windows

Comment: Um, "line by line" kinda assumes source code... Also strongly suggests that the OP does not know the difference between source and binary. :)

Comment: I m trying to write a C program that can read another program and give it to the processor for execution.

Comment: @ask:  Could you be more specific, and edit your specific issue into your question?  Right now, it's headed towards being closed as "not a real question".  Exactly what do you want to do?  Give a detailed example.

Answer (score 0):

Read in the program, put it into a file, compile, link and execute it?

C isn't Perl if that is what you are looking for.

Frank

Comment: Eg: i hav a program to print "hello world" (program 2). So i need a program in C that could read program 2 and execute it( by giving the program to the processor for execution). then i need to get the output of program2

Answer (score 0):

Yes. It is not only possible, but done all the time. UNIBASIC & UNIBASIC DL4 are two of the languages that I've used that are written in C.